# command line compilation for connection to Oracle db

Tags: java

I managed to compile and run the following code in *netbeans* but I wanted to compile and run using command line statement:

```
javac –cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\lib\odbc7.jar" OracleDBConnect.java
```

then run:

```
java OracleDBConnect.java
```

But I get the error

```
no suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class OracleDBConnect {

  public OracleDBConnect() {

     try {
     // Load MS access driver class
     //   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
       // System.exit(0);
     }
       String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
       String userid = "HR";   // Username here
       String password= "HR";     // Password here        

       String sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES";

      try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url, userid, password);
          Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ))
      {
          ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
      }
      catch (SQLException e)
      {
          System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     new OracleDBConnect();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the classpath when you run the class:

```
java –cp “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\lib\odbc7.jar” OracleDBConnect
```

It is not needed to include `odbc7.jar` when you compile it since you do not directly reference a class from it.

Comment: Thx, just trued the above. It compiles fine and created the OracleDBConnect.class. However, when I run it as you suggest, I get the message "Error: Could not find or load main class OracleDBConnect".

Comment: this means that Java cannot find your OracleDBConnect.class. You need to add its directory to the classpath: `java -cp <path to the class directory>;<path to obbc7.jar> OracleDBConnect`

Comment: thx. Unfortunately I get the error "no suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" again.

Comment: java -cp “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\lib\odbc7.jar”;. OracleDBConnect

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependent libraries in the classpath and execute `java`, ex: `java -cp <libs ; separated> ClassName`